# How to correctly connect data from two tables?

Tags: php, mysql

How to correctly connect data from two tables?
My base structure given:

```
Table1: clubs - id_club, club_name.  

Table2: table- id, id_club, games, points, set_win,set_lost.
```

I have manually added data to the database. I have entered id_club in the "table" table, but I can not display the name club_name

```
require_once('conect.php');
$result = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabele ORDER BY points DESC, (br_strz - br_str) DESC");
$result->execute();
$results = $result->fetchAll();
foreach ($results as $index => $row)
{
  ?>
  <tr>
    <td><label><?php echo ($index + 1);?>  </label></td>
    <td><label><?php echo $row['club_name']; ?></label></td>
    <td><label><?php echo $row['games']; ?></label></td>
    <td><label><?php echo $row['points']; ?></label></td>
    <td><label><?php echo $row['set_win'];?> : <?php echo $row['set_lost'];?></label></td>
  </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: have you tried `JOIN`ing them?

Comment: normalize your database and use JOIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the table in your sql query to be able to access the data from the club table.
So the query should look something like

```
SELECT * FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table2.id = table1.table2id
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Please tell me how to connect it with my PHP code. Or should I add it to MyAdmin only where? I tried to add it in the SQL section and i click "GO" but it still does not work. In what section should I add this in MyAdmin?

Answer (score 0):

You have to join the club_id with club.id to get club_name.

Answer (score 0):

You can JOIN 2 tables. You can use your query like this:

```
SELECT `t1`.*, `t2`.*
FROM `Table1` `t1`
   INNER JOIN `Table2` `t2` ON `t1`.`id_club` = `t2`.`id`
ORDER BY `t2`.`points` DESC, (br_strz - br_str) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use join as per your requirement

```
SELECT column_name(s)
FROM table1
JOIN table2 ON table1.column_name = table2.column_name;
```

for more info please visit :- https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp